# Joining two tables in one datagrid usig Linq C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, join, datagrid

I want to join two tables into one datagrid. table one: **tblProjects** - table two: **tblEmployeeLoginDetails**

In this method- `private void FillProjectsDataGrid()` I want to fill my datagrid using this coding:

```
            dgViewProjects.ItemsSource = DC.tblProjects.Where<tblProject>(c => c.ProjectID != null)
                .Select<tblProject, ProjectData>(m => new ProjectData()
                {
                    ProjectID = m.ProjectID,
                    Name = m.ProjectName,
                    Status = m.ProjectStatus,
                    Employee = m.EmployeeName,
                });

            dgViewProjects.ItemsSource = DC.tblEmployeeLoginDetails.Where<tblEmployeeLoginDetail>(c => c.LoginID != null)
                .Select<tblEmployeeLoginDetail, EIDData>(m => new EIDData()
                {
                    UserID = m.LoginID,
                    Name = m.EmployeeName,
                    Surname = m.EmployeeSurname,
                    Email = m.EmployeeEmailAddress,
                    Password = m.EmployeePassword,
                    Role = m.RoleID.ToString(),
                    Department = m.EmployeeDepartment,
                    IDNumber = m.EmployeeIDNumber,
                    Gender = m.EmployeeGender,
                    Date = m.EmployeeDOB.Value,
                    HomeAddress = m.EmployeeHomeAddress,
                    Telephone = m.EmployeeTelephoneNumber,
                    City = m.EmployeeCity,
                    Province = m.EmployeeProvinceCode,
                    SetImage = m.EmployeeProfilePicture
                });
```

For **tblProjects** I use this class:

```
public struct PDData
{
    public string _project;

    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
}
```

For **tblEmployeeLoginDetails** I use this class:

```
public struct EIDData
{
    public string _sts;

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string IDNumber { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public Binary SetImage { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to join these two tables and display the information in one datagrid. I have tried a Linq join statement but I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Haze.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[Haze.tblProject]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Haze.tblProject]'.

And lastly here is my join coding:

```
        List<tblProject> Join = (List<tblProject>)from u in DC.tblEmployeeLoginDetails
                                                  join b in DC.tblProjects
                                                  on u.LoginID equals b.ProjectID
                                                  where b.ProjectID != null
                                                  select b;
```

I have no idea how to join these two tables together using the classes that I have to display it in one datagrid. If anyone has any advice or help, please don't hesitate to leave a comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a new anonymous class with both the employee and project details from your join.  The join you have was only returning values for the projects

```
    var Join = (from u in DC.tblEmployeeLoginDetails
                                              join b in DC.tblProjects
                                              on u.LoginID equals b.ProjectID
                                              where b.ProjectID != null
                                              select new {Project=a, Employee=b}).ToList();
```

Then you would have to bind this to your datatable, something like this:

```
    dgViewProjects.ItemsSource = Join;
```

Your first block of code is going to overwrite the initial setting of the datasource with the second, not add to it.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you very much for the time and effort! :D

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
    List<tblProject> Join = (from u in DC.tblEmployeeLoginDetails
                                      join b in DC.tblProjects
                                      on u.LoginID equals b.ProjectID
                                      where b.ProjectID != null
                                      select b).ToList();
```