# How to set another datacontext to a specifig column (its content) on datagrid when the main datacontext is different?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid binded with a VM (the main datacontext of the window, i set it manually).

In the datagrid, there is a column with a foreign key. Instead of the foreign key, i would like to show the corresponding value of it (it's a string).

I've found this post but it doesn't work :

[WPF How to display relational data in DataGrid's TextBlock like in ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538676/wpf-how-to-display-relational-data-in-datagrids-textblock-like-in-combobox)

I'm very new to WPF so I don't master all about it.

So, I have 2 viewmodels : VM_Livre and VM_MaisonEdition.

In the initialization of the window, i have this :

```
      public EcranLivre()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LocalLivre = new ViewModel.VM_Livre();
            DataContext = LocalLivre;

            LocalMaisonEdition = new ViewModel.VM_MaisonEdition();

        }
```

So the datacontext of the whole windows is "LocalLivre", but in a datagrid, i wish one column is binding to "LocalMaisonEdition".

I tried relativeSource and such, but i don't really understand how to use it.

here is the code for datagrid :

```
        <DataGrid Name="dgLivres" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BcpLivres}"
                  Grid.Row="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ActiverBcpFiche, Mode=OneWay}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding LivreSelectionnee, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectionChanged="DgLivres_SelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding Path=L_IDLivre}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom" Binding="{Binding Path=L_Nom}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Résumé" Binding="{Binding Path=L_Resume}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Stock" Binding="{Binding Path=L_Stock}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Prix unit" Binding="{Binding Path=L_Prix_unit}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="N° Maison édition" Binding="{Binding Path=fk_ME_IDMEdition}" Width="*"/>


                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date d'entree" Binding="{Binding Path=L_DateEntre}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mail alerte" Binding="{Binding Path=L_MailAlerte}" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
```

Actually, the whole idea is that, i have 2 tables, the main datacontext is the table "T_Livre", and it has the foreign key "fk_....MEdition". I would like to show its corresponding value from the table "T_MaisonEdition", instead of the integer value.

I really don't know how to do it

Thank you

Comment: The datagrid dgLivres only has access to what you are binding the ItemSource to. In your case it is BcpLivres. If you want to access additional information, you may want to consider using a binding proxy.

Comment: @tabina I'm searching about it, but it seems kinda complicate (everything is still new to me in WPF). I'm still searching for solution thank you